# How do I look up GE Stock information?

Tags: ruby, arrays, if-statement

I am writing a program which allows the user to input a date and input the type of stock information they need for that specific date. All of the stock info and dates are in a separate CSV file. My program won't run and  I feel as though i am missing something. This is for a class and I would not like to use ruby's CSV class.

Here is a sample of what this file looks like:

```
date,open,high,low,close,volume,changed,changep,adjclose,tradeval,tradevol
2013-10-07,23.84,23.90,23.80,23.89,3522559,-0.16,-0.67%,23.89,83992937.36,8462
2013-10-04,24.18,24.18,23.90,24.05,33274615,-0.05,-0.21%,24.05,800232596.05,74361
2013-10-03,24.22,24.25,23.84,24.10,37466161,-0.23,-0.95%,24.10,902130194.02,95122
```

This is my program:

```
#open the file
data = File.open("data.csv","r+")

#make an empty hash
stocks = {}

contents = data.readlines
data.close

#this add quotes between each line
contents.collect! do |x|
    x.chomp
end
#this splits up each in into its own array

contents.collect! do |x|
    x.split(',')
end



contents.each do |x|
    stocks[x[0]] = x
end



puts "This program has all the General Electic stock information from November 27, 1960 to October 8 2013. Please enter the date you would like to find the stock information of like this: 1997-10-30 (year-month-day)."
#prompt user for the date of the stock info they would like to find
date = gets.chomp

data = stocks[date]


puts "Please enter what information about the stock you would like to know: open, high, low, close, volume, changed, percent change,adjusted closing, trade value, or trade volume. Please put a underscore in place of all spaces."
#get an input for what type of stock information the user would like
input = gets.chomp
#elsif statement to give the user the info they need based on what stock info they want


if input == open
   puts "The open of your stock is: #{data[1]}"
   elsif input == high
           puts "The high of your stock is: #{data[2]}"
   elsif input == low
           puts "The low of your stock is: #{data[3]}"
   elsif input == close
           puts "The close of your stock is: #{data[4]}"
   elsif input == volume
           puts "The volume of your stock is: #{data[5]}"
   elsif input == changed
           puts "The volume of your stock is: #{data[6]}"
   elsif input == percent_change
           puts "The percent change of your stock is: #{data[7]}"
   elsif input == adjusted_closing
           puts "The open adjusted closing of your stock is: #{data[8]}"
   elsif input == trade_value
           puts "The trade value of your stock is: #{data[9]}"
   else input == trade_volume
           puts "The trade volume of your stock is: #{data[10]}"

   end
```

Comment: That's a radical edit to your question's code, making the answers appear to be unrelated.

Answer (score 0):

Here's your code cleaned up a bit:

```
require 'csv'

puts "This program has all the General Electric stock information from November
27, 1960 to October 8 2013. Please enter the date you would like to find the
stock information of like  this: 1997-10-30 (year-month-day)."
date = gets.chomp

puts "Please enter what information about the stock you would like to know:
open, high, low, close, volume, changed, percent change,adjusted closing, trade
value, or trade volume. Please put a underscore in place of all spaces."
input = gets.chomp

CSV.foreach(
  'test.csv',
  :headers => true,
  :return_headers => false
) do |row|

  next unless row['date'] == date

  if input == 'open'
    puts "The open of your stock is: #{ row['open'] }"
  elsif input == 'high'
    puts "The high of your stock is: #{ row['high'] }"
  elsif input == 'low'
    puts "The low of your stock is: #{ row['low'] }"
  elsif input == 'close'
    puts "The close of your stock is: #{ row['close'] }"
  elsif input == 'volume'
    puts "The volume of your stock is: #{ row['volume'] }"
  elsif input == 'changed'
    puts "The volume of your stock is: #{ row['changed'] }"
  elsif input == 'percent_change'
    puts "The percent change of your stock is: #{ row['percent_change'] }"
  elsif input == 'adjusted_closing'
    puts "The open adjusted closing of your stock is: #{ row['adjusted_closing'] }"
  elsif input == 'trade_value'
    puts "The trade value of your stock is: #{ row['trade_value'] }"
  elseif input == 'trade_volume'
    puts "The trade volume of your stock is: #{ row['trade_volume'] }"
  else
    puts "An unknown option was entered."
  end

end
```

With these inputs:

```
1997-10-30
open
```

Returns:

```
The open of your stock is: 23.84
The open of your stock is: 24.18
The open of your stock is: 24.22
```

Use Ruby's CSV class. It's already written, and it's been debugged and tested so you don't have to reinvent that wheel. You can tell it to use the first line of the CSV file as headers, and whether those should be returned or not. Also, it can return a row of data as an array or a hash. Getting it back as a hash is very useful for what you want to do.

---

And here are some refactorings to show you how to simplify and remove redundant code:

```
require 'csv'

puts "This program has all the General Electric stock information from November
27, 1960 to October 8 2013. Please enter the date you would like to find the
stock information of like  this: 1997-10-30 (year-month-day)."
date = gets.chomp

puts "Please enter what information about the stock you would like to know:
open, high, low, close, volume, changed, percent change,adjusted closing, trade
value, or trade volume. Please put a underscore in place of all spaces."
input = gets.chomp

CSV.foreach(
  'test.csv',
  :headers => true,
  :return_headers => false
) do |row|

  next unless row['date'] == date

  case input
  when 'open'
    puts "The open of your stock is: #{ row['open'] }"
  when 'high'
    puts "The high of your stock is: #{ row['high'] }"
  when 'low'
    puts "The low of your stock is: #{ row['low'] }"
  when 'close'
    puts "The close of your stock is: #{ row['close'] }"
  when 'volume'
    puts "The volume of your stock is: #{ row['volume'] }"
  when 'changed'
    puts "The volume of your stock is: #{ row['changed'] }"
  when 'percent_change'
    puts "The percent change of your stock is: #{ row['percent_change'] }"
  when 'adjusted_closing'
    puts "The open adjusted closing of your stock is: #{ row['adjusted_closing'] }"
  when 'trade_value'
    puts "The trade value of your stock is: #{ row['trade_value'] }"
  when 'trade_volume'
    puts "The trade volume of your stock is: #{ row['trade_volume'] }"
  else
    puts "An unknown option was entered."
  end

end
```

This version replaces the `if/elseif/else` with `case/when` which helps streamline the logic, and returns the same thing for the same inputs.

---

```
require 'csv'

puts "This program has all the General Electric stock information from November
27, 1960 to October 8 2013. Please enter the date you would like to find the
stock information of like  this: 1997-10-30 (year-month-day)."
date = gets.chomp

puts "Please enter what information about the stock you would like to know:
open, high, low, close, volume, changed, percent change,adjusted closing, trade
value, or trade volume. Please put a underscore in place of all spaces."
input = gets.chomp

CSV.foreach(
  'test.csv',
  :headers => true,
  :return_headers => false
) do |row|

  next unless row['date'] == date

  val = case input
        when 'open'
          'open'
        when 'high'
          'high'
        when 'low'
          'low'
        when 'close'
          'close'
        when 'volume'
          'volume'
        when 'changed'
          'changed'
        when 'percent_change'
          'percent_change'
        when 'adjusted_closing'
          'adjusted_closing'
        when 'trade_value'
          'trade_value'
        when 'trade_volume'
          'trade_volume'
        else
          puts "An unknown option was entered."
          next
        end

  puts "The %s of your stock is: %s" % [val.gsub('_', ' '), row[val] ]

end
```

This builds upon the `case` statement, only returning what changes, but also showing us massive redundancy.

---

```
require 'csv'

puts "This program has all the General Electric stock information from November
27, 1960 to October 8 2013. Please enter the date you would like to find the
stock information of like  this: 1997-10-30 (year-month-day)."
date = gets.chomp

puts "Please enter what information about the stock you would like to know:
open, high, low, close, volume, changed, percent change, adjusted closing,
trade value, or trade volume. Please put a underscore in place of all spaces."
input = gets.chomp

CSV.foreach(
  'test.csv',
  :headers => true,
  :return_headers => false
) do |row|
  puts "The %s of your stock is: %s" % [input.gsub('_', ' '), row[input] ] if (row['date'] == date)
end
```

Stripping out the redundancy results in this code.

Comment: Can you show me how to do this without using Ruby's csv class?

Comment: While it's possible to rewrite a CSV module, I'm not going to try; I've been there and done that too many times in the past. CSV is a badly abused data format, and for simple tasks, writing a simple parser isn't hard. I could show you how but I'd charge you for it; You can figure out a simple one using `IO.foreach` and `String.split`, and, as long as you're not dealing with embedded commas you should be OK. But, *WHY* would you NOT want to use the built-in tools to do this? Ignoring the built-in functionality is a bad decision.